# RetryGatewayFilterFactory configuration in spring-cloud-gateway

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-gateway

I am working on a gateway project using `spring-cloud-gateway`. I can see the [Retry Filter](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-gateway/blob/master/spring-cloud-gateway-core/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/gateway/filter/factory/RetryGatewayFilterFactory.java) is already present in the project's source code.

But there are no documentation on how to configure it through yml congigurations. Any one worked with it or integrated with your project. Can anybody provide any lead.

Answer (score 0):

After checking the source code, I able to figure out the configurations. And it is working fine.

```
- id: retry_route
  uri: http://www.something.com/someurl
  predicates:
  - Path=/retryable**
  filters:
  - name: Retry
    args:
      series: SERVER_ERROR
      # Retry count starts at 0
      retries: 4 
      statuses: SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE,GATEWAY_TIMEOUT
      methods: GET,PUT
```

For `series,statuses` check [HttpStatus](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/HttpStatus.html)